# Mcafee endpoint encryption doesn't see previously encrypted partition after Windows 7 reinstallation

Tags: windows, disk-encryption

My partitions C and D were encrypted and Windows 7 was installed on C. I copied all important files to D and then changed harddrive controller from IDE to AHCI, removed C and created it again and then installed Windows 7 again. After windows was installed I installed mcafee endpoint encryption. It downloaded policy from server but didn't see D drive properly. OS showed D partition as RAW and mcafee showed C partition as encrypted and D partition as decrypted but it looked like not formatted.

Why is that happening? The only thing that I changed was IP address and HD controller in BIOS, everything else was the same as before, I mean all the devices, MAC address, host name, user name, password etc. There was no 100 MB system partition before but Windows installer created it when I created C partition but I don't really think it matters. Is there anything I did wrong?

I got xml file from someone responsible for encryption and tried to recover that partition using EETech, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: How was the drives encrypted? Full Disk? What program did you use?

Comment: Sorry, I mean mcafee endpoint encryption. I edited my question. All partitions were encrypted.